# Error with template class T with lists

Tags: c++

I am having an issue figuring out the error when it comes to using template classes and lists. here is the code. The errors i am getting are all on the same line and the are things like syntax errors, it says printList illegal use of type void and another error is unrecognizable template declaration/definition

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <deque>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
void printList<T>(const list& lst, string s) {

cout << s << ": ";
for (typename list::const_iterator i = lst.begin(); i != lst.end(); i++)
cout << *i << " ";
cout << endl;
}
```

It keeps giving me the errors on the line with `void printList<T>` Can someone please help me find out why this is happening?

Comment: Do you really need all of those lines in main to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: sorry about that. i removed the unecessary code

Comment: Use `list<T>` where you have `list` and remove the incorrectly placed `<T>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal way to declare the function would be:

```
template<class T>
void printList(const list<T>& lst, string s)
```

You'll also need to change

```
cout << s << endl;
```

to

```
cout << s.c_str() << endl;
```

OR more elegantly just

```
#include <string>
```

As well as the

```
list::const_iterator
```

to

```
list<T>::const_iterator
```

Otherwise you are not declaring the template type of your list object.

Comment: `cout << s.c_str() << endl;` is incorrect.  `string` works just fine with `cout`.

Comment: I mean s.c_str() works..., he will either need to use s.c_str() or include <string> for his code to compile (at least on my compiler).

Comment: Point out the missing include then.

Comment: Done.  I don't want to be the source of bad habits.